# Navigation Drawer with Activities goes into loop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am developing this application which includes Navigation Drawer with one base Activity and other activities which practically extend the drawer in order to avoid the creation of the same every time i load another activity, chosen from the drawer.

However, I have a problem at the very beginning when the drawer is initialized. As per many tutorials found online I use a switch for the drawer items to choose from. Hence, at the very beginning I want an Activity to be loaded when Bundles are null.

When trying to chose the appropriate but not the DrawerBase itself, I get an error which says:

**performing pause of activity that is not resumed**

Could anyone tell me what is the problem ?

I am not using onResume() at the BaseActvity nor at the Extending one.

I've tried with an activity which does not extend the base and works as a charm. I guess the loop continues and needs to be stopped at a time I guess.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why you'd want to do this. Since, you're writing a new app, you should probably just use fragments and I am pretty sure that'll resolve your problem.

Comment: I see, but switching now to fragments will take a lot of time and I guess I am not into the time of doing that. There must be an answer for this issue. I am not the first one to go this way. @ShivamVerma

Comment: Well, I think the problem could be with your `finish()` method. You might be calling it when you switch to another activity ?

Comment: Post a stack trace for logcat.

Comment: The most interesting is the part when the app does not crash, but keeps on loading. Now, after @ShivamVerma, told me to delete fisish, it does load but still takes time. I see the stack trace from logcat, nothing usual, just loading the menu.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I did it. Thank you.